# the android sdk requires android developer toolkit version 22.6.1 or above

Tags: android, adt

ADT opens up with the error message :

"The android SDK requires ADT version 22.6.1 or above"

Following approaches to update ADT fails :

1. Use SDK manager to update ADT plugins
2. Go to Help->Install New Software -> select android developers site -> update developer tools

the install new software fails with exception :

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=profile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.adt,22.6.0.v201403010043-1049357
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package,22.6.0.v201403010043-1049357
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.base,22.6.0.v201403010043-1049357
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms,22.6.0.v201403010043-1049357
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.gldebugger,22.6.0.v201403010043-1049357
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer,22.6.0.v201403010043-1049357
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.ndk,22.6.0.v201403010043-1049357
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview,22.6.0.v201403010043-1049357
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay,22.6.0.v201403010043-1049357
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.adt,22.6.0.v201403010043-1049357
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms,22.6.0.v201403010043-1049357
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.gldebugger,22.6.0.v201403010043-1049357
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer,22.6.0.v201403010043-1049357
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.ndk,22.6.0.v201403010043-1049357
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview,22.6.0.v201403010043-1049357
```

Comment: Strictly speaking the other Q is the dupe and not this one.

Comment: This question is not a dupe, the other question is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I reported [this bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=67325) yesterday. Solution is to use *Help -> Install new software* option with **httpS://** protocol (**s** is important). No special downloads or re-installations is needed, just choose the right update site.

Answer (score 6):

Follow the following steps to update to 22.6.1

1. Download ADT 22.6.1 archive from [here](http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-22.6.1.zip)
2. Open ADT, goto Help -> install new software -> Add site -> Select archive and select the      ADT22.6.1.zip downloaded in step 1.
3. Press OK, select developers tool and install
4. Restart ADT

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue where checking for updates couldn't find 22.6.1.

I resolved it by going to Help --> Install New Software and using the following update site:

https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

Alternatively, you can download a ZIP version of the 22.6.1 update site from here:

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html

Answer (score 0):

You can go to **Window->Android SDK Manager** and check tha what version you have.
In my case it shows I already have toolkit **22.6.1** installed **but still get the error**. Whether you already have it or not, you can do the following to fix.

- Go to **Help->Install New Software**... In the dialog shown below, click on 'Add' button on the top right side.
- Paste **"https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/"** in Location. You can name it anything.
- Click Ok and follow the dialog by clicking Next.
- If prompted with a message sasying you already have it, just agree so that it gets updated (or installed if it wasn't there).

This should resolve the issue.
source : [http://codewriterstips.blogspot.nl](http://codewriterstips.blogspot.nl/2014/03/android-sdk-requires-android-developer.html)